# Stick multiple divs to top of page as scrolled past

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I keep finding tutorials on how to stick a div to the top of the page as it's scrolled past, and then unstick if you scroll up over it, but I cannot seem to find one that will work for multiple divs.  I want to replicate the sort of scrolling that the iOS uses for music where you scroll past a letter and that letter knocks the previous one out and sticks to the top.

Please let me know if you can help!

I am not looking for code to be written, was just wondering if there any jquery plugins out there that I am not finding.

Comment: Morning, Drew. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow isn't a search-request forum. We also don't do your homework. We take a look at code and adjust it to fit the scope of the project. In this scenario, there is no code. Unfortunately, I'm going to vote to close this question. For future questions, [Please read the SO FAQ on Posting](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Thank you.

Comment: Can you post any html and/or script code you are currently having issues with? If you do, post it quickly before the question gets closed. Seems you only get half a chance do to so.

Comment: I was not looking for any code to be written, just wasn't sure if there were any plugins out there.  I have no code written yet, am just looking to do this in the near future and wanted to see if anyone knew something I didn't.

Comment: Try jQuery. I'm working on something like this myself, except I want each sticky div to add itself to the bottom of the last one as you scroll down, and remove itself as you scroll up.